# Ruby on Rails emails sent not received while on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku

I am having trouble trying to get a contact page to send emails correctly. The page is running ruby on rails hosted on heroku and according to the papertrail it is being sent without error. The log is as follows:

```
    Jun 12 15:14:37 dry-woodland-1410 app/web.1:  Processing by ontactController#create as HTML Jun 12 15:14:37 dry-woodland-1410 app/web.1:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",authenticity_token"=>"IRu+hjuGuo0Dw5hM0jOOAxFqyT6CXoubk5TocJqw7w4=", "message"=>{"name"=>"example", "email"=>"example@example.com", "subject"=>"subject", "body"=>"body"}, "commit"=>"Send"} Jun 12 15:14:38 dry-woodland-1410 app/web.1:    Rendered contact_mailer/new_message.text.erb (0.1ms) Jun 12 15:14:38 dry-woodland-1410 app/web.1:  Sent mail to contact@akimono.com (127ms) Jun 12 15:14:38 dry-woodland-1410 app/web.1:  Redirected to http://dry-woodland-1410.herokuapp.com/products
```

Here is the code for the contact controller:

```
    class ContactController < ApplicationController
def new
    @message = Message.new
    @cart = current_cart
end
def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @cart = current_cart
    if @message.valid?
        ContactMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
        redirect_to(products_path, :notice => "Your message was successfully sent. If you do not hear back in one business day please resend.")
    else
        flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
        render :new
    end
    end   
    end
```

and here is the code for the contact new view:

```
    <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
    <fieldset class="fields">
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :subject %>
    <%= form.text_field :subject %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body%>
    <%= form.text_field :body %>
</div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="actions">
<%= form.submit "Send" %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

I've looked all over the place and can't figure out why a message isn't actually being sent and no error message is being thrown even though everything seems to be in place.

The contact mailer code:

```
    Name: <%= @message.name %>

    Email: <%= @message.email %>

    Subject: <%= @message.subject %>

    Body: <%= @message.body %>
```

Comment: Does this work locally?  What addon are you Using?  Sendgrid?  Can we see the code for `ContactMailer`?

Comment: It doesn't throw errors locally, but I couldn't get it to send emails locally either. I don't think I had any addons for email.

Comment: First thing i would do is get it working locally.  Minor tangent; you may want to set up [mailtrap](http://mailtrap.io/).  It has helped me debug many Mailer issues and lets you see all formats of the email (text, html, etc.).
After that, you'll want to setup the free sendgrid on [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid)